# Providing user specified location for extracting packages in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-package, geoprocessing-package, layer-package

In ArcMap the folder location used to unpack packages dragged into a map can be set using the Customize | ArcMap Options > Sharing tab:

[image]

I just looked for the equivalent option in ArcGIS Pro on the Project Page | Options but it has no Sharing tab:

[image]

Is the only way to control this by using the output folder of the [Extract Package](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/extract-package.htm) tool instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has not been implemented yet. I asked the responsible team about this not long ago. It is on their to-do list.

(I don't have access to their queue, thus I can't get a tracking number, nor can I speak to when it might be implemented.)

For now, the only way to control package output is by using the Extract Package tool as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Settings in ArcGIS Pro seem to be more project based than application based, so I doubt there would be a setting like the ArcMap one.

As most tasks in ArcGIS Pro are run from geoprocessing tools, I imagine the geodatabase or locations specified in Environments would be used for any/all geoprocessing tasks, including the Extract Package tool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An odd thing is that the Sharing As A Layer Package dialog appears in a Package Layers pane that is separate from the Geoprocessing pane that is used to house the Extract Package tool dialog. Even though there are no Sharing options there, that is a place that I had not thought to look for them.